# How to create workflow for approval/rejection

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a workflow for an approval request.

Once the request is approved, it should assign a task to a particular user.

If rejected, it should send an email to the user who created the item.

I can't get the workflow to fire. What I have is below.

[image]

Comment: Instead of `If Variable:Outcome equals Approved`, try `If Variable:IsItemApproved equals Yes`? I know that I've run into this same issue before, and I *think this is how I fixed it.